# Winapi . TrackPopupMenuEx equivalent in CreateWindow

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi

When we create a pop up menu we call a function TrackPopupMenuEx  . It displays a shortcut menu at the specified location and tracks the selection of items on the shortcut menu .
If you specify TPM_RETURNCMD in the fuFlags parameter, the return value is the menu-item identifier of the item that the user selected. If the user cancels the menu without making a selection, or if an error occurs, the return value is zero.
This command is blocking ie unless we click on menu or outside we are blocked.

I have created a window which has various static items which acts like a popup menu. Is there some function equalient to  (TrackPopupMenuEx with TPM_RETURNCMD ) which can tell me which was the last WM_COMMAND CLICKED which is blocking . If a function does not exist , how can we create a good blocking in the view that  it doesn't eat up the CPU in wait cycle.

What I did :

In the WM_COMAND I initialize the global variable which is whatIsLastClicked.  In my function i wait till this variable is set but it seems to eat cpu.

Some code

```
    WNDCLASSW wc = { 0 };
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)COLOR_WINDOW;
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hInstance = hInst;
    wc.lpszClassName = L"mywindowsclass";

    wc.lpfnWndProc = windowprocedure;
//<== all handlers WM_COMMAND defined in this fucntion 
 
    if (!RegisterClassW(&wc))
    {
        return -1; // registration failed
    }

 
    HWND hWnd = CreateWindowW(L"mywindowsclass",
 L"My window", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE, 
 100, 100,   500, 500, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
 
 //POINT : need some blocking code here which is efficient to find what i clicked
```

Comment: in `WM_COMAND` exist Control identifier and Handle to the control window. and of course not need any global variable

Comment: Sorry . Did'nt get . The procedure to handle ie WM_COMMAND is  defined in a function told to class while registering the class .  The main just registered and called create window .

Comment: *need some blocking code here which is efficient to find what i clicked* ?! what is this mean

Comment: I have created a window which has various static items which acts like a popup menu.  .   WM_COMMAND  handled the functionality which is done  .     Just like TrackPopupMenuEx with TPM_RETURNCMD helps us with a blocking call with identifier of which menu was clicked , i need  a blocking call which helps me identify the window i clicked inside the main window . Hence a blocking call is needed . I also want it to be efficient

Comment: you got in window procedure all info. what else you need ?

Comment: I might not click on the opened window for 3 hours but code will move away after create window . I need at the last comment  , after createwindow ,  a code which is blocking till i hit a window and that should tell me which window i hit

Comment: you never need code here which blocking

Comment: The blocking code you want is a message loop.

Comment: You can use **multiplethread** and **MsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx** to get a good blocking in the view that it doesn't eat up the CPU in wait cycle.

Comment: There is a big parent window which has a message pump . I created this child  window which is somehow receiving the messages without need of a message pump.  if i create my own message loop the system goes into a hang like state for the child window . 

while (GetMessage(&msg,/* NULL*/childHandle, NULL, NULL))
 {
   
  TranslateMessage(&msg);
         DispatchMessage(&msg);
  }